# Enterprise, two stores, hierarchy only works on one store

Tags: magento

So, I have an EE build, which has multiple stores.

I have some CMS pages, which are shared across the stores, using the hierarchy settings to create sub-pages. So essentially in the browser the URL should be http://www.example.com/page1/page2 which works in one store, but on the other store I can only access the subpage directly using its URL key, not through its parent.

Anyone come across this before or any ideas on what to try?